# Extracting numbers from a string in C++

Tags: c++, stringtokenizer

Suppose I have the following char array:

```
char *word="R12_X8_10";
```

The number of digits are not fixed but the locations with respect to the non-numeric characters are fixed. How can I extract the numbers without boost? I  should get {"12", "8", "10"} by splitting the word.

This is supposed to be an easy task as I have done in Java many times but the in C++ it is taxing my brain.

Comment: std::regex + std::atoi

Comment: Yep, C++ is taxing brains alright.

Comment: The declaration `char *word="R12_X8_10";` is invalid C++ anyway, fix that one first.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ stream way would be to get or simply ignore the *marking* characters. For example to ignore them you could use:

```
const char *word = "R12_X8_10";
int i, j, k;
std::stringstream ss(word);

ss.ignore(1) >> i;
ss.ignore(2) >> j;
ss.ignore(1) >> k;
```

or even (more compact if not more readable):

```
((ss.ignore(1) >> i).ignore(2) >> j).ignore(1) >> k;
```

(unrelated, but note the `const` for `word` because a string litteral should not be assigned to a non const pointer).

Comment: This is actually a C++ solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
int a,b,c;
char *word="R12_X8_10";
    sscanf(word,"R%d_X%d_%d",&a,&b,&c);
```

I know this is a c++ system, but I also know that scanf and sscanf work with c++ compiler if stdio.h in included.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `sscanf()` works in C++ all right, but `char *word = "...";` does not. And header should be <cstdio>

Comment: You are right, I just tried it. Point is Hassan is not going to declare the string that way. It's just an example

Comment: @Nitro, your suggestion is a good and easy one.  I can convert the *char to std::string if needed. Thanks.